# Tosafos - Not a mitzvah to live in Israel since can't keep the land mitzvos

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, eretz-yisrael, tosfot

[Tosafos in Kesubos 110b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.110b.14?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Ketubot.110b.14&lang2=bi) writes:

> הוא אומר לעלות כו' - ...והיה אומר רבינו חיים דעכשיו אינו מצוה לדור בא"י כי יש כמה מצות התלויות בארץ וכמה עונשין דאין אנו יכולין ליזהר בהם ולעמוד עליהם:
>
> He says to go up [to the Land of Israel], etc.: ...And Rabbenu Chaim says that today, it is not a commandment to live in the Land of Israel, as there are several commandments that are dependent upon the land - and several punishments - that we are not able to be careful about and to be cognizant of.

I don't understand this svara. Why should one be dependent on the other? Maybe there is a mitzvah to live there today, just it's difficult to keep practically due to the mitzvos that depend on the Land which can't be practically followed. Does Tosafos simply mean it's not recommended? Also why does he say there are mitzvos that depend on the Land which have a punishment for being neglected. To me this sounds like they're obligatory on a biblical level. I assume the mitzvos don't apply today midoraisa, so why would there be a punishment.

If someone could explain this Tosafos I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The most important thing to keep in mind with this is the history. Meaning that it was written at the time of the Ba'alei HaTosafot. What the condition was in the land of Israel then is not what is in the land of Israel today.

Comment: Why would one only be punished for biblical violations? It sounds like it is mostly a limmud zekhut. FWIW many poskim dismiss it out of hand and don't even try to explain it, e.g. Shu"t Mahari Ben Lev (3:41), and Shu"t Torat Hayyim (3:41). See also Shu"t Maharit (2:28) who claims that Rabbenu Hayyim never said this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** There are multiple approaches to Rabbenu Hayyim. In summary: Either A) Rabbenu Hayyim's view is incomprehensible and he never said it (Maharit) or B) He did say it. Accordingly, either B1) he said it but it is still incomprehensible (Shelah), or B2) he said it and it is comprehensible. Accordingly, either B2a) Rabbenu Hayyim holds that that there is actually still a mitsvah today, just that practically it is inadvisable (Haflaah), or B2b) he holds that that the mitsvah does not apply today. Accordingly, either he holds B2b-1) that there is nevertheless still a mitsvah kiyyumit if one lives in Israel (R. Feinstein), or B2b-2) he holds the mitsvah is entirely inapplicable today. Accordingly, either he holds B2b-2a) that the mitsvah only applies when one will practically carry out the mitsvot of the land (R. Klein), or B2b-2b) he holds that the mitsvah simply does not apply today, regardless (Beit Halevi).

---

Many poskim reference the view of Rabbenu Hayyim, but most do not attempt to explain his position. Indeed, [R. Yishmael Hakohen of Modena](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%94) (cited in Daf Al HaDaf to Ketubot there) basically asks your question that "danger" and "no mitsvah" are two different things.

Additionally, the [Shelah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Horowitz) (Shaar HaOtiot: Kof: Kedushat HaMakom 452) writes that besides for being a lone view, R. Hayyim's view basically doesnt make any sense for the reasons you outlined: That as with all mitsvot one is obligated to try to follow them, and if one does it is a mitsvah. Why should this be any different, and why is it impossible to do the mitsvot?

> דברי רבינו חיים הם דברי יחיד. וגם לא מסתברא טעמיה, דעל זה נאמר (הושע יד, י) 'וצדקים ילכו בם ופשעים יכשלו [בם]', דודאי מי שדר בארץ ישראל ואינו מקיים מה שמחויב לקיים אז הוא פושע, אבל המקדש עצמו ומקיים, לענין תרומות ומעשרות ושביעית כפי מה אשר מחויב, אז אשריו. ומה שאמר דאין אנו יכולין ליזהר בהן, זה הדבר אין מובן אצלי. דלמה אין יכולין ליזהר, ומי הוא המונע. על כן אין להשגיח בדבריו אלו.

One posek who does suggest an approach is [R. Menashe Klein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menashe_Klein) who writes in Shu"t Mishneh Halakhot (8:11) that according to Rabbenu Hayyim, the very mitsvah of living in Israel is itself dependent on fulfilling the mitsvot there. If one may not be able to fulfill the mitsvot, then one would not even be obligated to live there. In passing he mentions that the purpose of God bringing us into Israel was to fulfill the mitsvot, as though this is the reason why only when one knows that he will fulfill the mitsvot is he even obligated:

> נלפענ"ד לחדש **דס"ל לרבינו חיים ז"ל דמצוה זו של ישוב ארץ ישראל קשורה בקיום שאר המצות** כלומר דהגם דישנם מצות התלויות בארץ שאפשר לקיימם גם היום מ"מ כיון דלאו כל המצות אפשר לקיימם וישנם מצות שא"א לקיימם ממילא ליכא כלל מצות ישוב ארץ ישראל דאותה מצוה לא הוי בכלל מצוה אלא כשאפשר לקיים כל המצות התלויות בה וכל שא"א לקיים כל המצות אלא מקצתן יהי' מאיזה טעם שיהי' אז ליכא חיוב לדור שם והדר שם אינו מקיים מצות ישוב א"י הגם שישנם כמה מצות התלויות שמקיים וודאי יש לו שכר על קיום הני מצות מ"מ **לענין מצות ישוב ליכא רק באופן שאפשר לקיים כל המצות התלויות בארץ שהוא כעין תנאי במצות ישוב הארץ דליכא מצוה אלא באפשר לקיים כל המצות דע"מ כן הכניסנו הקדוש ברוך הוא לא"י** ולכן בזה"ז שא"א לקיים ליכא מצות ישוב א"י דהו"ל כחסר בתנאי המצוה ולכן ס"ל לר"ח הכהן שפטור, ובאמת כי רבינו חיים לא כתב פטור אלא דליכא מצוה כלומר דאינו מצוה כלל לדור שם דהמצוה תלוי בתנאי הנ"ל

Another posek who addresses this is [R. Moshe Feinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein) (Igrot Moshe EH Vol. V: 23). He again basically asks your question that whether or not one will have difficulty doing the mitsvot should have nothing to do with whether or not there is a mitsvah. Furthermore, he asks that nothing should have changed today; he assumes that it always would have been difficult keeping all the mitsvot in Israel, and that even R. Hayyim would concede that there used to be an obligation. If so, what changed?

He answers that in the opinion of R. Hayyim there isn't really an obligation today, just a mitsvah if one does. Accordingly, if one will have difficulty with the mitsvot, one is not obligated:

> וצריך לומר דיש חילוק גדול. דבזמן הבית ודאי יש חיוב גדול על כל אחד מישראל לגור בארץ ישראל, ששם הוקבע מקום כל ישראל לגור שם ולהתחייב בכל המצוות התלויות שם. ולכן ודאי אין יכול מחשש שלא יוכל להזהר בהמצוות והענשים ליפטר מחיובו, דהם ככל המצוות שאינו רשאי לבקש תחבולות ליפטר מהן.
>
> אבל בזמן הזה שנגלינו מארצנו, ואין זה עתה בעוה"ר המקום הקבוע לדירת כל
>   ישראל, ואין שייך כלל שיתחייבו כולם ליסע לשם לקבוע דירתם. ורק שמצוה
>   בעלמא ודאי מקיים כשגר בארץ ישראל, אבל לחייב מחמת מצוה זו ליסע לארץ
>   ישראל אין שייך כשאין בית המקדש קיים ואנו בגלות, לכן כשהוא חושש שלא
>   יוכל לעמוד עליהם שקשה ליזהר, אין עליו לחוש למצוה זו אף שודאי יש מצוה

This is very related to his responsum (EH Vol. I: 102) in which he is asked whether the halakha follows Ramban that the mitsvah of living in Israel applies today, or R. Hayyim Kohen's view. He answers that while the majority follow Ramban, that it is obvious that that is only a mitsvah kiyyumit, not an actual obligation (he does not differentiate, but presumably means that *today* it is not a full obligation). His proof is that poskim don't say it is forbidden to live outside of Israel, and Rambam just writes it is forbidden to leave. (Of course Ramban is coming to argue on Rambam in the first place, and R. Feinstein's whole point is that we hold like Ramban, so proving Ramban's position from Rambam is questionable).

In this, R. Feinstein was mostly anticipated by the [Beit Halevi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Dov_Soloveitchik_(Beis_Halevi)) (Shu"t Vol. II: 50:3) who indicates that the reason of Rabbenu Hayyim would not be coherent were there an actual mitsvah to live in Israel. If there were, one would simply have to try one's best. However, his opinion is understandable in light of Rambam's view that the mitsvah of settling Israel does not apply today. Accordingly, the reason to live there would be in order to fulfill the mitsvot that can only be performed there. Accordingly, once that isnt practical, then the whole reason to live there today in the first place doesn't apply. Like R. Feinstein he predicates the view of Rabbeu Hayyim on there not being an actual obligation to live in Israel toady. However, according to R. Feinstein there is still a mitsvah kiyumit, while according to the Beit Halevi, there is no mitsvah at all today.

Unlike Rabbis Feinstein and Klein who assume that according to Rabbi Hayyim there is actually no mitsvah at all today, The [Haflaah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinchas_Horowitz) to Tosafot there writes that R. Hayyim doesn't mean that the mitsvah actually doesn't apply, but that although one is obligated to live in Israel and is sinning from refraining, he is avoiding bigger sins that he would encounter in not following halakha properly in Israel:

> ה"נ אף דאין מצוה משום שיבא לידי קלות במצוות באיסור חמור [במצוות] התלויות בארץ, עבירה היא

Importantly, however, [Maharit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Trani) (Shut Vol. II YD 28) argues at length that Rabbenu Hayyim Kohen never said this. He asserts that this is a later addition, and in reality he only said that in time of danger the mitsvah is not obligatory (as with any other non-cardinal mitsvah). One his pieces of evidence is the Hagahot Mordekhai (Ketubot 2:313) which quotes what Rabbenu Hayyim wrote and mentions only the issue of danger:

> ומכאן אתה למד שדברי הר' חיים אינן מיסוד התוס' ...והאיר את עיני שמצאתי בהגהות מרדכי כלשון הזה כת' רבינו חיים כהן בתשובה דה"מ בימיהם שהיה שלום אבל עכשיו שהדרכים משובשים אינו יכול לכופה דהו"ל כמו חפץ להוליכה למקום גדודי חיה ולסטים ואפי' אם יעמיד לה ערבים מגוף לממון ערביך ערבא צריך ע"כ הרי שתשובת הר' חיים כהן ז"ל לא באה אלא מטעם סכנת הדרכי' ומ"ש בתו' דאין מצוה לדור בא"י הגהת תלמיד היא ולאו דסמכא היא כלל

Similarly, see [Agudah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Suslin) to Ketubot (Ch. 13:171).

Comment: I am not endorsing a particular position; merely presenting them...

Answer (score 1):

The *Baal Tosafot* seems to be saying that *yatza scharo b'hefsedo* - the potential merit of living there is overshadowed by serious infractions he is likely to commit, thereby voiding the moral imperative to live there.

Comment: So no mitzvah means not recommended?

Comment: 'Moral imperative'? Do you mean mitsvah?

Comment: It seems to be saying that both the positive things that one should fulfill and the prohibitions that one should avoid violating are impossible at that time. (אין אנו יכולין לזהר ולעמוד)